# Firebase downloadUrl and Access token conflict

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I am working on a simple app using Flutter to retrieve an image I manually uploaded to my firebase storage and display it on the screen. The upload is always successful, but I cannot get the image because the "dowloadURL" is showing "access token" instead.

Am i missing something somewhere? Someone please help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8plC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uploading the file and directly get the image downloadUrl after, I've made some static functions which I call on my page like this:

```dart
StorageUploadTask imageUploadTask = await ImageProcessProvider.setImageToStorage(_destinationImage, generatedRandomId);
String imageDownloadUrl = await ImageProcessProvider.getImageDownloadUrlAfterUploading(imageUploadTask);
```

Static functions (including how I upload: 'setImageToStorage'):

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:image_picker_modern/image_picker_modern.dart';

class ImageProcessProvider {
  static Future<String> getImageDownloadUrl(String imageId) async {
    try {
      final String downloadUrl = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(imageId + '.jpg').getDownloadURL();
      return downloadUrl;
    } catch (error) {
      print('getImageDownloadUrl: $error');
      throw error;
    }
  }

  static Future<String> getImageDownloadUrlAfterUploading(StorageUploadTask uploadTask) async {
    try {
      final StorageTaskSnapshot url = (await uploadTask.onComplete);
      final String downloadUrl = (await url.ref.getDownloadURL());
      return downloadUrl; 
    } catch (error) {
      print('getImageDownloadUrlAfterUploading: $error');
      throw error;
    }
  }

  static Future<StorageUploadTask> setImageToStorage(File image, String imageId) async {
    try {
      final String fileName = imageId + '.jpg'; 

      final StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
      final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(
        File(image.path),
        StorageMetadata(
          contentType: 'image/jpeg',
        ),
      );

      return uploadTask;
    } catch (error) {
      print('setImageToStorage: $error');
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for this. Will give it a try... But what I want to have clarifications on now is that, from the image I uploaded, why is it Access token I am getting there instead of preferably the downloadUrl there so I can copy it or something... Thanks for the reply earlier

Comment: Maybe something went wrong while uploading, can't help you besides trying uploading on a different way I described above.

Comment: Thanks a lot... This saved me a whole lot of stress I did not know about

Comment: Glad I could help @knight